# Where is it described that the part of Ethshar seen in the books is the flat end of a cylinder?

Tags: the-legends-of-ethshar

It's a  matter of common knowledge for readers of Lawrence Watt-Evans's *[The Legends of Ethshar](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheLegendsOfEthshar)* series that ["The World appears to be the end-cap of a cylinder surrounded by a noxious yellow gas"](https://ethshar.fandom.com/wiki/The_World), to quote the wiki. I was recently quoting it to someone and it struck me that I had no idea where the idea came from. The wiki is, of course, fan-edited, but [Lawrence Watt-Evans has stated in a FAQ he wrote](http://www.ethshar.com/ethsharfaq.shtml):

> If the material here isn't enough to satisfy you, some of my readers have created the Misenchanted Wiki, compiling a huge amount of information about Ethshar. Most of it is even accurate, and when I see something there that isn't I usually (not always) correct it.

That suggests that there probably is some reason why people have stated the shape of a cylinder. I haven't had a chance to read the books in some years (and my local library doesn't seem to carry copies). Is the shape of the world stated in one of the novels? In supplementary material? A statement from the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be in reference to a passage from [*The Unwilling Warlord*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/422225.The_Unwilling_Warlord). Our hero Vond travels to "*the edge of the world*" and looks over the edge. What lies beyond is an unbreathable yellow haze.

> They had, indeed, come to the top of the yellow fog, but they had been unable to see over it or through it; all they had seen was a seemingly-infinite expanse of golden haze, stretching on before them forever, while behind them all the Small Kingdoms were laid out, the central mountain-chain curving down between the rich green coastal plain and the paler, drier eastern lands. The ocean appeared on the west­ern horizon, the burning sands of the great deserts on the eastern, and still they saw nothing to the south but golden haze.
>
> ...
>
> The edge looked like an ordinary cliff; it was not particularly straight or even, but just a place where the dunes ended in a drop-off.
>
> What made it unique was that it extended as far as Sterren could see in both directions, and that he could see nothing at all on the other side except that infinite golden mist.
>
> ...
>
> Almost immediately, he stopped and flew back. He turned to Sterren and said, amazed, “There’s no air! I couldn’t breathe. And that yellow stuff smells horrible, and it burns your throat. And I still couldn’t see any bottom. The mist just goes on forever!”
>
> .....
>
> “Sure!” Vond said. “I’ll need to see how thick it is, though.”
>
> “How thick what is?”
>
> “The World, of course!” He bent over, and Sterren watched as a narrow hole appeared in the sand before him.

We also have confirmation from [*Tales of Ethshar*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13664797-tales-of-ethshar) that the world is indeed flat. There's no particular indication that it's a *cylinder*, though, other than that it appears to have a reasonable amount of depth.

> About half the inhabited World is the Hegemony of Ethshar, ruled by
> the overlords of its three great cities: Ethshar of the Rocks, Ethshar
> of the Sands, and Ethshar of the Spices. To the north of the Hegemony
> lie the Tintallions, the Baronies of Sardiron, and anarchic lands like
> Srigmor; to the east are the Small Kingdoms, more than a hundred tiny
> squabbling states. To the south and west is only ocean, right to the
> edge of the World — **yes, the World is flat and has edges**. It has two
> moons, one pink, the other orange. The greater moon follows a
> thirty-day cycle much like our own moon’s, while the lesser moon goes
> through all its phases in about a day and a half.